# What to do for a duplicate of an erroneously closed duplicate?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, duplicate-questions

[This question (1)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23414281/497418) is a duplicate of [another question (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13352080/497418). The second question (2) was marked as a duplicate of [another question (3)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2148728/497418).

The problem is that the second question (2) is not actually a duplicate of the third question (3), due to the nuance between checking the start of an HTML attribute and checking the start of a CSS class *within* an attribute. It's not much of a difference, which explains the closure of 2 as a dupe of 3.

How should this duplication be addressed? I could vote to reopen #2, and vote to close #1 as a duplicate of #2, or I could just leave both of them alone.

Comment: close 1 as a duplicate of 2 and open 2, in my opinion. 2 already has a few good answers and definitely isn't a duplicate of 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vote to reopen the question that is erroneously closed.  If at all possible, edit the question to clarify how it is different from the question it is closed as a duplicate of.  If there is a subtle point that prevents the duplicate from applying, emphasize that point so that other readers will understand why it's not a duplicate.

You can go ahead and close the remaining question as a duplicate of the other, if it has an adequate answer.