# How to treat an answer that is correct, but not what you wanted?

Tags: discussion, support

I have one question that was [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35615257/1233788). During the analysis of the answer, I noticed it didn't answer what was my original problem. But looking again my question I noticed that I didn't specify the question enough.

so now I have this dilemma:

> By only reading what was wrote in the question the answer is correct. But not solve my problem. Now I see two possible actions:

Update my question to specify better, and as consequence of this action not mark the answer as correct (because it isn't going to be correct).

Check the answer as correct, and create another question very much similar to the first one but more specific. (Making this new question possible vulnerable to be marked as duplicate)

**My question** is how of these are the better approach? Or there is other approach I can make?

Comment: New question as Servy answered is the way. To avoid "duplicate of previous" you actually need to explain why it is not a duplicate (and link to your previous question). If it took *you* some time to figure out that you did not ask what you want it is much harder to others to spot difference. (Basically follow regular rules for "reopen duplicate" like http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253140/what-to-do-for-a-duplicate-of-an-erroneously-closed-duplicate *before* posting the question)

Comment: "Check the answer as correct" - that is not what that check is for. You check the answer you personally accept, it does not indicate the one question that is correct as several answers can be correct for different reasons. Point one then becomes "Update my question to specify better, and as consequence of this action not mark the answer as accepted, because it is not correct *for me*". But it might be for someone else.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is inappropriate to change what the question is asking simply because you now realize that you didn't ask what you wanted to ask.  If you realize that you now have a new question that you want to ask, you need to ask it as a new question.

Whether you choose to accept the existing answer or not is entirely up to you.